# Val_loss metric error in Keras/TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am currently trying to write a neural network for a multi-class classification problem using early stopping monitoring validation loss, but I keep receiving the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available.
```

The code for my network is below:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=10)

model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[early_stop])
```

EDIT:

I have uninstalled and reinstalled all packages and am now receiving this error instead:

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node loss/output_1_loss/Cast (defined at /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_938]
```

Comment: (30, 4) is the shape

Comment: X_train - 120, 4.    X_test - 30, 4.    y_train - 120,      y_test - 30,

Comment: And they are not one-hot encoded but are scaled (min max scaler)

Comment: I am now getting the same error with a new warning: Cast string to int64 is not supported (there are no NaN values)

Comment: If your labels are in shape (120,) and (30,) how does your last layer have 3 neurons?? Either your last layer should have 1 neuron, or you should have 3 labels for each sample. Or you should use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` if your labels are one number include 0,1 or 2. Otherwise you will get error. Also try to convert your data to float before passing to model.fit, i.e. `X_train=np.array(X_train).astype(np.float32)` and do this for x_test, y_test, y_train.